# Broadcasting dynamic dimension in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, array-broadcasting

I am using Tensorflow from python. I have two tensors I wish to concatenate (it could also be another operation, I don't think the exact operation matters to this question). These tensors have their shapes defined as (N1 != N2 are positive integers):

```
a: (None, N1)
b: (1   , N2)
```

Since I will be concatenating along the last axis, it seems like this operation could be performed. But tensorflow refues. The code

```py
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

N1 = 2
N2 = 3
D1 = None

a = keras.Input(shape=(D1, N1))
b = keras.Input(shape=(1, N2))

c = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([a, b])
```

fails with

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, None, 2), (None, 1, 3)]
```

The closest I have come to making this work is by using `RepeatVector` as below, but unfortunately, this only works with static dimensions, not dynamic ones:

```py
N1 = 2
N2 = 3
D1 = 7

a = keras.Input(shape=(D1, N1))
b = keras.Input(shape=(N2))
b_repeated = layers.RepeatVector(D1)(b)

c = layers.Concatenate()([a, b_repeated])
```

Any suggestions of how to concatenate -- i.e. do the right broadcasting or repeating -- with such `None` dimensions would be much appreciated!

Comment: You cannot directly concatenate tensors with shapes `(None, N1)` and `(1, N2)` along the second axis, as the message says, every other dimension (here only the first one) should have the same size. Do you want to repeat the second tensor as many times as the first dimension of the first tensor and _then_ concatenate?

Comment: Repeating the tensor and then concatenating would be perfectly fine! Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do that with a lambda layer:

```
import keras
from keras import layers
import keras.backend as K

N1 = 2
N2 = 3
D1 = None

a = keras.Input(shape=(D1, N1))
b = keras.Input(shape=(N2,))
c = layers.Lambda(lambda ab: K.concatenate([ab[0], K.repeat(ab[1], K.shape(ab[0])[1])],
                                           axis=-1))([a, b])
print(c)
# Tensor("lambda_1/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 5), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Since I was also dealing with some higher-rank tensors, I found `keras.backend.repeat_elements` to be very useful also, since it can deal with non-rank-2 tensors.